# How to remove both duplicated values from two csv files in apache spark?

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

Newbie to apache spark. What I want to do is to remove both the duplicated keys from two csv files. I have tried dropDuplicates() and distinct() but all the do is remove one value. For example if key = 1010 appears in both the csv files, I want both of them gone. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using Spark Dataframes.
First create two dataframes from CSV files:

```
val df1 = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("file1.csv")
df1.show
+----+
| key|
+----+
|1010|
|1234|
+----+

val df2 = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("file2.csv")
df2.show
+----+
| key|
+----+
|1010|
|1221|
+----+
```

Then to find out unique values in both CSV files perform following operation: `(df1 U df2) - (df1 ∩ df2)`

```
val unique = df1.union(df2).except(df1.intersect(df2)).show
+----+
| key|
+----+
|1234|
|1221|
+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

thx for @himanshulllTian's great answer. And I want so say some more. If you have several columns in your file; then you just want to remove record based on the `key` column. Also, I don't know whether your csv files have same schema.  Here is one way to deal with this situation. Let me borrow the example from himanshulllTian.

First, Let's find the records that share some key: `val dupKey = df1.join(df2, "key").select("key")`. Then we can find the part we hope to remove in each dataframe: `val rmDF1 = df1.join(dupKey, "key")`. Finally, same except action: `val newDF1 = df1.except(rmDF)`.

This maybe trivial. But work. Hope this help.

Comment: You are right @G_cy. The solution provided above is good in case we consider only one column in dataset. But, if we consider whole record as unique set then it will work as expected.